# codeigniter benchmark {memory_usage} security

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm making a website with codeigniter.

If a user writes `{memory_usage}` in his comment `2.75MB` will be shown to him. doesn't it bring security vulnerability to codes written by codeigniter? Any reasonable(and common) way to prevent such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your controller:

```
$this->output->parse_exec_vars = FALSE;
```

**Parsing Execution Variables**

> CodeIgniter will parse the pseudo-variables `{elapsed_time}` and
>   `{memory_usage}` in your output by default. To disable this, set the
>   `$parse_exec_vars` class property to `FALSE` in your controller.

**Update**, you may need to modify a core file in `/system/core/Output.php`

Change:

```
protected $parse_exec_vars = TRUE;
```

To:

```
public $parse_exec_vars = TRUE;
```

Now you will be able to set `$this->output->parse_exec_vars` to `FALSE` in your controller.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property CI_Output::$parse_exec_vars `

Comment: `echo CI_VERSION;` => 2.1.3

Comment: I see. Think it is a bug. Updated my answer. Should fix the problem now.

Comment: Looks like the latest version of CI has already updated this, see here... https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Output.php#L105

Comment: downloaded the latest: http://c303150.r50.cf1.rackcdn.com/CodeIgniter_2.1.4.zip it still lacks update of github